# Is it possible to to configure NAT Gateway without using Internet Gateway with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, aws-nat-gateway

This is my code:

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to to configure NAT Gateway without using Internet Gateway with Terraform?

The code which I wrote for deploying the cod with terraform but I keep getting this issue:

[image]

This is the error I get:

Comment: Afaik it is possible in AWS to deploy a private [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) but the [VPC troubleshooting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/nat-gateway-troubleshooting.html) page suggests that "A NAT gateway must be created in a VPC with an internet gateway." So it sounds like you need IGW, but can designate it as private.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes. Is it what you need? It depends on what the purpose of your NAT Gateway is.

The [AWS NAT Gateways documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) explains that there are two different types of NAT Gateways:

1. Public NAT Gateways which are meant to route traffic from (and optionally, to) your private subnets to the internet.
2. Private gateways which are for routing traffic between your private subnets and transit gateway or a virtual private gateway.

For private gateways you don't need an Internet Gateway. With Terraform, you can create a private gateway by adding the `connectivity_type: "private"` argument to your `aws_nat_gateway`.

However, for public gateways, you do need an Internet Gateway. If you didn't have one, how else would you route traffic to the internet?

Comment: Now I'm trying to connect 2 private subnet together